# I'm the sea and the sun

Tags: riddle

Let us begin at the beginning
With all my mates and endless spinning
I'm not so hot and not so cold
I'm the sea and the sun, and quite as old

When shove comes to push
In your hand, I'm worth more than a bush
Day in, day out, hidden talents
Up and down, I keep the balance

I give birth to the flow
Downhill my children go
Through me you can see clearly
Now name me, riddler, dearly

Comment: you're back!!!!

Comment: [I am the sky and the dawn and the sun](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ze9kMoMfxYA)?

Comment: @Randal'Thor *Someone* has a good taste in music... :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is

> spring

Great thanks to jafe and Brandon_J

Let us begin at the beginning

> spring --> beginning of the year

With all my mates and endless spinning

> other seasons, rotating every year

I'm not so hot and not so cold

> spring is a season where the temperature is moderate

I'm the sea and the sun, and quite as old

> nice one! sea+sun sounds like season, where spring is one of them

When shove comes to push

> when force is applied

In your hand, I'm worth more than a bush
Day in, day out, hidden talents
Up and down, I keep the balance

> spring balance

I give birth to the flow

> spring as in water flow

Downhill my children go

> a stream of water usually flows downhill

Through me you can see clearly

> we can see through water clearly

Now name me, riddler, dearly

> spring

Why posting this riddle in this time of the year?

> Spring Equinox?

Comment: Yay! Way to go to put it all together.

Comment: Great solution! Often this kind of question attracts many interpretations, but this seems pretty infallible enev before any OP confirmation! +1

Answer (score 12):

Can't yet fit all of the clues together (and I am on mobile), but it does look like

> Maybe a spring (ecological) or the water table?

Because

> Downhill my children flow - springs birth water which flows downhill; not so hot, not so cold - springs usually have consistent temperatures; keep the balance - suggests water table and/or springs replenishing the water.

Comment: Could be rot13(fcevat gur frnfba, fcevat gur zrpunavpny qrivpr, naq fcevat va gur jngre frafr)?

Comment: Your work will not go to waste