# Dreadful Dastardly Diseases, or Always Atrocious Ailments

Tags: open-ended

So the other day, I was in a pharmacy and I saw that they had a "cold 'n' cough" medicine. The alliteration caught my eye, and I wondered it would be possible to create alliterative names with other ailments. "Fever 'n' flu" was the obvious next choice.

Well, of course there was a puzzle in the making - and here it is:

---

### The Puzzle:

> Create as many pairs of alliterative ailments as possible. Each pair is worth one point; if one illness or symptom often occurs simultaneously with its pair, that pair is worth two points. Diseases may not be used more than once in an answer - this is mostly to make things easier for you guys so you don't need to worry about permutations. If the ailment is not recognized by WebMD, it doesn't count.

Example:

```
Fever & Flu        2 points
Cold & Cough       2 points
Mumps & Measles    1 point
~Total:~           5 points
```

Everyone is allowed to use the above pairs, so you basically start with five points.

> **How many points can you get?**

Also,

> A bounty will be awarded if your solution is longer than a CVS receipt. I suppose that means I won't be giving out a bounty, but who knows! You guys are pretty clever. Also, potentially "paying it forward" on Avigrail's generous bounty on [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/80951/im-the-sea-and-the-sun).

---

### *This puzzle is technically "off-topic" now, due to the consensus reached in my [meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles). I recognize this and am voting to close this question.*

Comment: Uhhh what do you mean a CVS receipt? Also, wouldn't this potentially be too broad?

Comment: How long is your CVS receipt? (*Eyes on the bounty when no one is looking*)

Comment: @North CVS receipts are [famously very long](https://www.vox.com/the-goods/2018/10/10/17956950/why-are-cvs-pharmacy-receipts-so-long). Also, I don't think that this is too broad; it fits the open-ended tag fairly well. If you want, I can find a link to a similar question.

Comment: @Xilpex ahhh...I dunno. Maybe 100+ points? If I think it looks worthy of merit, I'll hand it a bounty.

Comment: @North I should probably require it to be recognized by some doctors' agency so that we don't have fake diseases pop up.

Comment: Cooould the downvoter please explain the downvote?

Comment: Sweats & Squits ?

Comment: Not a downvoter, but I'm not sure how puzzly just listing out medical ailments is. Unless the puzzle is trying to guess which ones occur together?

Comment: @noedne good point. This probably isn't my best puzzle, and I don't mind the downvote, either. What bugs me is when I get a downvote with no feedback. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my contribution
1)

> Asthma & asphyxiation (+2)

2)

> Meningitis & malaise (+2)

3)

> Flushing (of skin) & flu (+2)

4)

> Common cold & congestion (+2, imma make a case right now it should be worth more for triple alliteration :P)

5)

> Diabetes & dehydration (+2)

6)

> Colorectal cancer & constipation (+2)

7)

> Pneumonia & phlegm (+2?)

8)

> Depersonalization disorder & deliriuim (+2)

9)

> Demyelinating disease & deafness (+2)

10)

> Poliomyelitis & paralysis (+2)

11)

> Vertigo & vomiting (+2)

12)

> Immunodeficiency & infections (+2)

13)

> Croup & coughing (+2)

14)

> Hypoglycemia & hyperventilation (+2)

15)

> Heat (stroke) & hyperthermia (+2)

16)

> Hypercapnia & hypoventilation (+2)

17)

> Dyspnea & discomfort (+2)

18)

> Lyme(disease) & lethargy (+2)

19)

> Stroke & spasms (+2)

20)

> Hemophilia & hypovelimia (a.k.a bleeding) (+2)

21)

> **Coronary** artery disease (CAD) & **Cardiac** arrest (+2)

22)

> Alzheimer's & amneisia (+2)

23)

> Artheritis & aching (+2)

24)

> Pox (i.e. smallpox, chicken pox, etc.) & pus (+2)

25)

> Septicemia & skin (discoloration) (+2)

26)

> Hangover & hyperacusis (+2)

27)

> Migraine & misophonia (+2)

28)

> **Post**-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD) & panic (attacks) (+2)

29)

> Burns & blisters (+2)

30)

> Inflammation & irrittation (+2, irritation on the skin, mostly, not as in @North is irritating)

31)

> Fatigue & fever (+2)

32)

> Hemorrhagic stroke & headache (+2)

34)

> Hypovolemia & hyperaldosteronism (+2)

35)

> Hemorrhage & hematesis (+2)

36)

> Hyponatremia & hypervolemia (+2)

37)

> Palpable purpura & pleuritic pain (+2)

38)

> 

This is currently 74 points

Comment: MOre will be added, but I have to go, and I needed to save :P. Pretend like this doesn't exist right now

Comment: I wish that was funny, but unfortunately colorectal cancer is one of the top five most prevalent cancers in the U.S. and about 200,000 cases are reported *per year*. About 50,000 people die from it per year. Fortunately, there's a 64% survivle rate! That's also why they stick a camera up your a** at fifty to prevent the cancer.

Comment: Also the constapation comes from the cancer can potentionally literally obstructs the passage of excretion coming out, so it's actually pretty gross :/

Comment: @Brandon_J your cvs receipt is coming soon... how many items didd you purchase?

Comment: 74 points, but I'm gonna add more. Should you make a limit?

Comment: Well, this puzzle fell flat on its face. I'm giving you a checkmark and calling it a day.

Answer (score 6):

1. > Hepatitis & Hyperacusis
2. > Schizophrenia & Scleroderma
3. > Alzheimer's  & Aspergers
4. > Chickenpox & Chikungunya
5. > Lyme & Lupus
6. > Malaria & Meningitis
7. > Plague & Polio
8. > Smallpox & SARS
9. > Tetanus & Tinnitus
10. > Varicella &  Variola
11. > Zika & Zoster
12. > Dementia & Dystonia
13. > Sinus & Celiac
14. > AIDS &  amnesia
15. > Appendicitis & Anorexia
16. > Asthma & Arthritis
17. > Botulism & Bulimia
18. > Narcolepsy & Necrophilia
19. > Parkinson's & PTSD
20. > Pompe's & Pyromania

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Don't forget to use the ">!" spoiler notation in your answer.